# Should i use httphandlers or web services?

Tags: wcf, httphandler

I have a simple scenario where i want to output only json to the user.Now should i use a simple httphandler, call it from jquery and get the json or create a WCf service?

I want to use WCf service but don't see any advantage, maybe someone can point few of them and scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything would be suffice. Your thoughts are in correct direction, why to create a wcf service and increase the overload(maintaince, deployment etc).

If you are using Ajax, Look in to [PageMethods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/), which would even free you from creating a separate HTTPHandler and you could call your code behind methods directly in your javascript.

I am assuming you are using asp.net.

Comment: Then what are Web Services for? I mean if HttpHandlers can serve asynchronous calls and are easy to maintain why do people build Web services atall? Can't i just build a httphandler or something like this instead of Web services and it can still make my code interoperable between systems or Web services are build for interoperability only which httphandlers dont provide?

Comment: Yes, exactly you can do it! Both Web Service and asp.net pages work on same protocol i.e. HTTP. Just the Web Service, uses another protocol over HTTP i.e SOAP. SOAP, with extra overhead gives you more finner grain control over your messages. If you want to build restful web service, you could entirely do it with the help of HTTP handler(if you remember our discussion from yesterday) by just calling the correct method by parsing URL and HTTP Method(if you remember our discussion from yesterday :) ).

Comment: I am glad that you are now asking the correct questions. I think it would be helpful if you go through difference between Rest and Soap service. Why people actually take the burden of using a protocol which requires specialised tools for cosumption and creation. There are pros and cons of each of approach. Start from here http://geeknizer.com/rest-vs-soap-using-http-choosing-the-right-webservice-protocol/

Comment: You could see this example in which, a Rest Service is created using asp.net 2.0. The Rest Starter kit provided by microsoft, just eases the work that you have to do(method, url mapping, content type etc)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29706/REST-Web-Services-in-ASP-NET-2-0-C

Comment: We need a transport protocol + message protocol for communication. In case of Web service it is Http + SOAP, right? Now if it is Rest based, then it is Http + simple xml/json. In case of Http handlers, again it is Http + anything correct? So these are just mechanisms, SOAP is popular because it is widely accepted. Also    i am consfused why WCF default bindings still use SOAP + http if Rest is becoming popular and is lightweight, is it just for interoperability ?

Comment: WCF was built to extend old ASMX services and give you power of infinite configuration. ASMX service where only able to run on HTTP, but with WCF, you write the code and then you could decide any transport you want, be it HTTP, TCP. So the advantage is, you write code once and then depending upon its uses you just need to change its end point of where it should be exposed. Now a days for a web facing services, REST is become de-facto standard. That's why Microsoft launched, REST starter kit to build restful services using WCF(but in this case, the transport has to be HTTP)

Comment: HTTP is not only limited with xml+json content type. The complete list of mime type could be found here http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml
So, for every HTTP request, you could send response, which is the list above. The beauty of this - think for an example where the server on request sends some sale data. So if the request is from computer browser- it could send you HTML(mime type text/html). If the request is from a hand held device(and appropiate choices are made in http header), the server could serve you an image instead. single resource now has multiple represntation